# Where are bug reports saved?

Tags: launchpad, ubuntu-bug

where are bug reports from ubuntu-bug saved? Or how can I upload ubuntu-bug files as further information in launchpad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add more information from comment field . if you want to upload any files can choose attachments.

look at the image

[image]

yes you can save the BUG reports to a file and you can upload them manually

1 . **Offline Method**
For a bug report about a system crash:

```
apport-cli -p <package name> --save bug.crash
```

For a bug report about any other issue:

```
apport-cli -f -p <package name> --save bug.apport
```

2.**Adding apport-collect information to an existing Launchpad bug**

```
apport-collect <your bug_number here >
```

3.**Adding attachments to an existing Launchpad bug**
 for Linux pkg's

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

for non-linux pkg's

```
ubuntu-bug my_crash_report.crash
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: ya, but the main problem is that I dont know where to find the uvuntu-bug reports that I want to add. :)

Comment: To complete the answer you could include that crash files are stored in `/var/crash/`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Crash_reports